# DHL XML API Integration error "SV012a" and "SV014a"

Tags: php, api, dhl

Well, actually I am doing some steps by using the API with our application.

**(Note: I have taken all the below details from testing xml file provided by DHL Toolkit apart from Shipping and Billing Account Number)**

```
use DHL\Entity\GB\ShipmentResponse;
use DHL\Entity\GB\ShipmentRequest;
use DHL\Client\Web as WebserviceClient;
use DHL\Datatype\GB\Piece;
use DHL\Datatype\GB\SpecialService;
//echo __DIR__ . '/../../init.php';exit;
require(__DIR__ . '/../../init.php');

// DHL Settings
$dhl = $config['dhl'];
//echo "<pre>";print_r($dhl);exit;
// Test a ShipmentRequestRequest using DHL XML API
$sample = new ShipmentRequest();
//echo "<pre>";print_r($dhl);exit;
// Set values of the request
$sample->MessageTime = '2019-03-17T09:30:47-05:00';  
$sample->MessageReference = '1234567890123456789012345678901'; 
$sample->SiteID = $dhl['id'];
$sample->Password = $dhl['pass'];

$sample->RegionCode = 'EU';
//$sample->RequestedPickupTime = 'Y';  
$sample->NewShipper = 'N';  
$sample->LanguageCode = 'en';
$sample->PiecesEnabled = 'Y';
$sample->Billing->ShipperAccountNumber = $dhl['shipperAccountNumber'];
$sample->Billing->ShippingPaymentType = 'S';
$sample->Billing->BillingAccountNumber = $dhl['billingAccountNumber']; 

$sample->Consignee->CompanyName = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV Life Centre';
$sample->Consignee->addAddressLine('Central 1');  
$sample->Consignee->City = 'Singapore';  
$sample->Consignee->PostalCode = '486048';  
$sample->Consignee->CountryCode = 'SG';
$sample->Consignee->CountryName = 'Singapore';
$sample->Consignee->Contact->PersonName = 'raobeert bere';
$sample->Consignee->Contact->PhoneNumber = '11234-325423';

$sample->Dutiable->DeclaredValue = '2.00';  
$sample->Dutiable->DeclaredCurrency = 'EUR';

$sample->ShipmentDetails->NumberOfPieces = 1;

// All optional but add some data
$piece = new Piece();
$piece->PieceID = '1';
$piece->PackageType = 'EE';
$piece->Weight = '5.0';
$piece->DimWeight = '1.0';
$piece->Width = '2';
$piece->Height = '2';
$piece->Depth = '2';
$sample->ShipmentDetails->addPiece($piece);

$sample->ShipmentDetails->Weight = '5.0';
$sample->ShipmentDetails->WeightUnit = 'K';
$sample->ShipmentDetails->GlobalProductCode = 'P';
$sample->ShipmentDetails->LocalProductCode = 'P';
$sample->ShipmentDetails->Date = date('Y-m-d');
$sample->ShipmentDetails->Contents = 'For testing purpose only. Please do not ship';
$sample->ShipmentDetails->DimensionUnit = 'C';  
$sample->ShipmentDetails->CurrencyCode = 'EUR';

$sample->Shipper->ShipperID = $dhl['shipperAccountNumber'];
$sample->Shipper->CompanyName = 'University of QA';
$sample->Shipper->addAddressLine('1 New Orchard Road');
$sample->Shipper->addAddressLine('Senate House');
$sample->Shipper->City = 'London';  
$sample->Shipper->PostalCode = 'WC1E 7HU';  
$sample->Shipper->CountryCode = 'GB';
$sample->Shipper->CountryName = 'United Kingdom';
$sample->Shipper->Contact->PersonName = 'Mr peter';
$sample->Shipper->Contact->PhoneNumber = '11234-325423';

//$sample->EProcShip = 'N';  
$sample->LabelImageFormat = 'PDF';  

// Call DHL XML API
$start = microtime(true);
//echo $sample->toXML();
$client = new WebserviceClient('staging');
$xml = $client->call($sample);
echo "<pre>";print_r($xml);exit;
```

With this I am getting errors like below:

> SV012a
>        The system could not verify your shipping
>       account number. Please correct this number and
>       resubmit.For assistance call DHL customer services
>
> SV014a
>        The system could not verify your billing
>       account number. Please correct this number and
>       resubmit.For assistance call DHL customer services

But I am just testing the flow of requesting the “Shipment Validation” process from one the testing environment URL.
The URL is https://xmlpi-validation.dhl.com/serviceval/jsps/main/Main_menu.jsp

Steps:

1)  Click on “Shipment Validation”

2)  Click on “XML Services”

3)  Click on “Request_Global_EU”

4)  Click on “Submit”

While doing this process, I am getting an error like “The system could not verify your shipping account number. Please correct this number and resubmit.For assistance call DHL customer services” in your testing environment.

So, for that I am not able to test the request and response for “Shipment Validation”.

Any suggestion or guidance would be appreciate. 
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like either you do not have a valid ShippingAccount number or you are using a demo ShippingAccount with which you cannot modify most of the shipping request parameters with your own. And if you do, you will get the response you shared.

Comment: I had the same issue, that is why I mentioned the above. you do not have the right credentials, even though you think you do.

DHL give you staging and live credentials, it looks like you dont have valid credentials. You need to contact DHL represenatative